# Why does applying page element style remove class

Tags: html-editor, style-library

We've set up a page in Office 365 that has the following in the HTML for the page (not the master page)

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="some-random-other-class">
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>This thing</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the trouble is that when I apply a Page Element style from the style menu to an element inside the `row` div (e.g. the "This thing" paragraph in the example above):

[image]

It wipes out some of my classes:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="some-random-other-class">
            <p>hello</p>
            <h1>This thing</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to understand why it does this - has anyone else run into this before? Is there some reason behind this, or have I uncovered a bug in the editor?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky. There are some issues with the style menus. Basically, when it need to apply a style, it changes the vicinity as well. One thing you can do is get the class some-random-other-class and apply the parent div the 'row class' style as it describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326499/apply-css-styles-to-an-element-depending-on-its-child-elements).

Then take the parent of row class and assign cont class style there.

Another good old way is entering the header 1 tag manually.

Comment: Cool, I like this answer, it's a bit nicer than some other solutions I've seen. Unfortunately we can't enter the `h1` tag manually as it is going to be clients adding these styles. The way I actually solved this was to move the wrapper divs out into the page layout rather than the RTE, but that's not a general solution.